# Mysql Grouped Count Row of data in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Cant seem to figure this one out.

I need to returned a sum row of data based on a date range. The problem is the summed row can have multiple products. Let me show you example data.

```
|id|product_id|in|shelf|date      |
|1 |1         |2 |4    |2017-01-01|
|2 |2         |1 |5    |2017-01-01|
|3 |4         |2 |4    |2017-01-02|
|4 |8         |4 |8    |2017-01-02|
|5 |1         |3 |6    |2017-01-02|
|6 |2         |2 |3    |2017-01-02|
|7 |1         |2 |4    |2017-01-03|
|8 |2         |1 |8    |2017-01-03|
|9 |4         |2 |4    |2017-01-04|
|10|8         |4 |8    |2017-01-04|
|11|1         |3 |6    |2017-01-04|
|12|2         |2 |3    |2017-01-04|
```

So in the example data I want to know the sum of the in & shelf column for the dates from the 1st to 4th. But I only want the sums of product_id 1 & 2 combined in dates.

So the result I would like to see is below. Ie date range of the 1st to the 4th of January.

```
|date      |total|
|2017-01-01|12   |
|2017-01-02|14   |
|2017-01-03|15   |
|2017-01-04|14   |
```

Hope you can advice.

Comment: By, "Ie date range of the 1st to the 4th of June." did you mean January? Bender lately? :P

Comment: I did mean January...  I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could be you need a sum  of the columns

```
select date,  sum( in + shelf) as total 
from my table 
where date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-04'
and product_id in (1,2)
group by date
```

Comment: Thanks but its not getting me totals per day plus not grouped by the product_id of 1 and 2

Comment: looking to your data should return the total for day  .. and i have added  the filter for product_id (1,2)  .. answer updated .

Comment: data shows January, questions states June.  I'm confused.

Comment: the answer  is based on sample provided .. seems all january dates

Comment: I have tried the query.. The IN part fails.. It only manages to count 1 product_id and not the pair of them.

Comment: looking to the sample you provided  should sum the value for product 1a and 2